# Python style: which one should I use: for k in dict: or for k in dict.keys():?

Tags: python

For the explicit principle,  `for k in dict.keys():` seems better.

For simplicity, `for k in dict:` seems better.

Please help me to make a decision.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops

Comment: Thank you for the link @tomgalpin. I mainly want to know from style's point of view, which one is more beautiful. I adjusted my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

> For functionality, are they exactly the same?

Pretty much yes. `dict.keys()` actually returns a *dict view* which is a set, so you can do a few more things with it, but for iteration they'll do the same thing.

> For the explicit principle, for k in dict.keys(): seems better.
>
> For simplicity, for k in dict: seems better.

In my experience, both are *rarely* useful, it's much more common to want and use `dict.items()` (which really is what the default iterator should have been).

As a result I would recommend `dict.keys()` to express that you really actually want to iterate on or manipulate dict keys, and are not just misunderstanding what dict iteration does.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I inclined to use dict.keys() too.